# Round Robin Scheduling with arrival time and priority level

Tags: operating-system, round-robin

I have this Round Robin problem that I was wondering whether it was correct or not. The lower the number the higher the priority.

The Table is:

```
                 p0              p1           p2
Arrival Time     3ms             0ms          1ms 
Burst Time       3ms             25ms         7ms
Priority          1               7            5
```

With a time quantum of 5 ms.

This is my Gantt Chart:

```
  p1   p2   p0   p2                p1
0----1----3----6----11------------------------35
```

My understanding is that if it is preemptive and using priority then if during any given time a process with a higher priority enters the ready queue and the current process has a lower priority then it is preempted. Is my chart correct?

Comment: Assuming p1 is the highest-priority thread, I would expect it to run continuously from t=0mS to t=25mS (i.e. until the end of its burst time, if I understand the term correctly).  The round-robin aspect only comes into play if two threads have the same priority.

Comment: Should've mentioned that lower number = higher priority. Also, I am not sure if that is the case. If the question asked to use priority scheduling then I would do it how you said (assuming 7 was the highest priority) but this question specifically asks to use Round Robin.

Comment: One things is missing, is p0 coded into a wait after 3ms(non-preemptive way) ? Another question, is there any algorithm here of starvation avoidance ? And how the priority is set ? Is it fixed ? If there is priority then how it can be regarded as round-robin ?